# how to perform formatting in google sheets with text containing wildcard or "or" expression?

Tags: google-sheets, wildcard, conditional-formatting

i want to perform format cells which contain characters "A" or "B" in google sheets

i have attempted "Text contains"

```
A,B
A|B
(A|B)
"A"|"B"
"A" or "B"
```

none of them work

or should i try "custom formula is"?

What should i do?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the format rules choose 'custom formula' and then enter this formula

```
=regexmatch($B1;"A|B")
```

This should color the rows in the range B:C where the cells in column B contain A or B.

See if that works?

Comment: this is very good, the regular expression is working. but i don't understand the semantic of $, if i add it, it will highlight the adjacent cell which is not what i want

Comment: what i want to achieve is to treat 2 columns separately but to filter the same character groups.

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to get it working. Btw, The pipe ("|") charachter in regex means or.